# MYSQL query for a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called visitors which contains IP and country columns.

Now I want to query the table such that I get unique countries from the table and display the count of rows of that country.

Table:

```
IP         Country 
1.1.1.1.    xyz 
1.2.3.4     xyz
2.2.3.6     abc
3.61.3.69   axy
```

Now I want the result as :

```
Country     No_Visitors
xyz               2
abc               1
axy               1
```

I know how to do it by using 2 queries, get the unique country first and then again query the table for the country name. But how can I do it with single query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [**AGGREGATE FUNCTION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) `COUNT()` to get the total number of instances for each country.

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(IP)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Country
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c060/2)